Use tail probability to compute $E[X^2]$
It is well known fact that if $X$ is nonnegative r.v. then
$$
{E}[X]=\int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>x) \,d x.
$$
Suppose now I want to compute $E[X^2]$ using tail probability. Here is what I have tried:
\begin{align*}
{E}[X^2] &= \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X^2>x)\, d x\\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X>\sqrt{x}) + \mathbb{P}(X<-\sqrt{x}) \,d x\\
&= \int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>\sqrt{x})\, dx + \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X<-\sqrt{x})\, d x
\end{align*}
May I ask if this is correct?

Yes, it is correct.

And integration by parts, at least for a smooth density on $(0, \infty)$, gives $E[X^n] = \int_0^{\infty}, nx^{n-1}\mathbb{P}(X > x), dx$.

Yes, it's correct.
There are just two remarks to do: why you can separate the integrals and why all these functions are measurable in the first place.
For the first one, you can always do it when the functions are both non-negative or integrable (in this case both are true, but the positivity is obvious). For the other one, non-decreasing functions (like these) are always measurable: Increasing function is measurable (basically preimages of intervals are intervals).
When $X$ is non-negative, another useful identity is
$$\mathbb E[X^2]=\int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X^2>x)\text dx=\int_0^\infty 2t\mathbb P(X>t)\text d t$$
which follows from the substitution $x=t^2$.

Appreciate it! (Unconsciously) I must have been looking for those remarks:)
